# Вывод массива

Tags: c++

Условие:

> Дан одномерный массив из 100 элементов, состоящий из случайных вещественных чисел в диапазоне от -35 до 50. Вывести в порядке неубывания (возрастания) те положительные элементы этого массива, которые меньше заданного числа Х (0<X<50).

Мой код:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#pragma hdrstop

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float x[100] = { 0 }, sw, a;
    char j = 0, i = 0, min;
    randomize();
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        x[i] = random(85) - 35 + random(100) / 100.;
    printf("%f\n", x[i]);
    for (i = 0; i < 98; i++) {
        min = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < 99; j++)
            if (x[min] > x[j])
                min = j;
        sw = x[i];
        x[i] = x[min];
        x[min] = sw;
    }
    printf("Vvedite X:");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    i = 0;
    while (x[i] <= a) {
        printf("%f\n", x[i]);
        i++;
    };
    getchar();
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Вот у меня вывод неправильный... надо сначала вывести весь массив, а затем нужные элементы в порядке возрастания (работаю в Turbo C++).

Comment: аццкий код )

Comment: у меня не получилось по-нормальному записать,вроде и 4 пробела ставила,надеюсь админ отредактирует в норм запись...

Answer (score 1):

Отсортируй массив при помощи std::sort (если это всё-таки C++, что-то я не заметил по коду) или qsort. Потом выводи, начиная с конца, проверяя при этом число на принадлежность диапазону.

Comment: Если это тот Турбо C++, который запускался с дискетки, то в нем не было понятия пространства имен в привычном сейчас смысле и слова namespace

Comment: Тогда просто sort. А откуда там vcl? Разве в Turbo C++ она есть? Я думал, это только Delphi и C++ Builder.

Comment: qsort все таки
насчет vcl.h, то это все таки просто хидер, он ни к чему компилятор не обязывает. Это верно, если турбо с++ именно то самое - с под DOSа